# Center contents of div horizontally/vertically and align text to image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap div container split into 3 divs of equal sizes (widths are equal but not sure how to maintain height as well). I am not able to center the contents of it vertically and horizontally. Also, I am unable to figure out how to center a text that lies on the right of an image.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cjLadR/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gDrgJR/icon_2.png" alt="icon_2">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hm1Rk6/icon_3.png" alt="icon_3">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pj8n98f/1/)

And my expected output:

[image: capture]

Comment: I see HTML but I don't see the CSS of what you have tried. You are required to post all your markup that shows the problem here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explore using `flex-box` to leverage its precise positioning and allow (*let*) the browser do all the calculations and other heavy lifting.

I've also accounted for your `@media-query` to make the necessary adjustment at that viewport as well.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pj8n98f/3/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-fluid > div {
    background-color: #34caf7;
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-fluid > div > img {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.container-fluid > div > div {
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .container-fluid > div {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .container-fluid {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cjLadR/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gDrgJR/icon_2.png" alt="icon_2">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hm1Rk6/icon_3.png" alt="icon_3">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**A note on cross browser compatibility:**

`flex-box` has limited or no support for legacy browsers, refer to compatibility overviews before considering using in production - **If** supporting IE11 (*shudder*) is still a concern for you.

1. https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility

Comment: thanks! this is awesome. I will learn more on flex. Btw the responsiveness introduces some paddings when width goes down. Can you help me on that?

Comment: Are your referring to the padding in the `@media` breakpoint style rule? `.container-fluid > div {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        padding: 10px;
    }` I added this in to allow some breathing room between vertically stacked elements.

Comment: yes. I tried making it like `.container-fluid > div {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }` but cant get rid of the white space on the left/right of the tags when going down in width.

Comment: I see what you mean, just add a `min-width` of `100%` - `min-width: 100%;`

Answer (score 2):

So here you go.

1. If you are using bootstrap you can use the classes provided by it. `col-xs-*` this should be inside a class `row`. This is the bootstrap structure.
2. As you are asking to align the content center respective to your image as well as you need to add some more classes as an addition to it. Here I have added `menu-item` with `flex`.

Please do not overwrite the bootstrap class unless really it is necessary.

Try like this. I hope it is going to help you. Good Luck!

```css
.container-fluid > div {
  background-color: #34caf7;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-item img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.menu-item img + div {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cjLadR/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1">
        <div> Test comments </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gDrgJR/icon_2.png" alt="icon_2">
        <div> Test comments </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hm1Rk6/icon_3.png" alt="icon_3">
        <div> Test comments </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: For smaller screen]
[image: For bigger screen]

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is how bootstrap 3 structure should be used instead of just overwriting the base classes.

Comment: @nabanita can you convert stuff to % and post a code? With px it is not responsive at all.

Comment: @JackSlayer94 I have updated the same as you asked. This is completely responsive. Just I have used the bootstrap class `col-xs-*` for small screen and `col-sm-*` for other devices. Screenshot attached. Responsiveness is already taken care by bootstrap. You do not need any % based code for it. I hope this will help you and I will highly recommend you to follow the bootstrap classes & structure unless it is really required to add a media query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use display:flex on the `.container >div` together with `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center`

Also, if you are using bootstrap, why don't you structure your html in `row`s and `col`s ? That's what bootstrap is for :)

For example in your case use make a structure like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Anyway, see snippet below with the solution

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.container-fluid > div {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #34caf7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-fluid > div > img {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.container-fluid > div > div {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container-fluid > div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cjLadR/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gDrgJR/icon_2.png" alt="icon_2">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hm1Rk6/icon_3.png" alt="icon_3">
    <div> Test comments </div>
  </div>
</div>
```